# Update a user password in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I am new to jest and I have an update password endpoint which updates a user password perfectly but when I try to run the test using jest I get "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test" I feel I am doing it wrongly...

The code to update password:

```
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const User = require('../models/userModel');


exports.updatePassword = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // Get user from collection
  const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('+password');
  console.log(user);
  // Check if POSTed current password is correct
  if (!(await user.correctPassword(req.body.passwordCurrent, user.password))) {
    return next(new AppError('Your current password is wrong', 401));
  }

  // If so, update the password
  user.password = req.body.password;
  user.passwordConfirm = req.body.passwordConfirm;
  await user.save();
  // Log user in, send JWT
  // res.send('sent');
  createSendToken(user, 200, res);
});
```

What I tried for the test:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/userModel');

const userOneId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

const userOne = {
  _id: userOneId,
  name: 'blackcypher',
  email: 'blackcypher@gmail.com',
  password: 'comeonboys',
  passwordConfirm: 'comeonboys',
};

beforeEach(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tour-test');
  await User.deleteMany();

  await new User(userOne).save();
});

afterEach(async () => {
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});


test('Should update a user profile', async () => {

  const response = await request(app)
    .patch('/api/v1/users/updateMyPassword')
    .set(
      'Authorization',
      `Bearer ${jwt.sign({ userOneId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
      })}`
    )
    .send({ passwordCurrent: 1234, password: 12345, passwordConfirm: 12345 })
    .expect(200);
});
```

Comment: So it works in less than five seconds, when you use that endpoint "normally", and let an actual user set a new password? (Asking, because some password encryption algorithms are _deliberately_ designed to be "slow", to make attacking them with brute-force harder ...)

Comment: yeah, when I update a password it's works in less than 5 seconds